# trollop: negated flags not false, but nil

Tags: ruby, trollop

According to the [Trollop blog](http://masanjin.net/blog/label/trollop), boolean options in version 2.0 will result in that option either being assigned the value `true` or `false`.  An example from that website:

> E.g.:

```
 opt :magic, "Use magic", :default => true
```

> Using `--magic` will result in `:magic => true`, and `--no-magic` will
>   result in `:magic => false`, and not using either will result in `:magic
>   => true`.

Let's verify that.

```
jdibling@hurricane:~/dev/ruby/decoder$ cat hacks2.rb 
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'trollop'

options = Trollop::options do
    banner "tester for trollop"
    opt :magic, "Use magic", :default => true
end

puts "Args: #{ARGV}\nMagic: #{options.magic} (#{options.magic.class})"


jdibling@hurricane:~/dev/ruby/decoder$  ruby --version
ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-linux]
jdibling@hurricane:~/dev/ruby/decoder$ gem list --local

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

gli (1.3.0)
trollop (2.0)
jdibling@hurricane:~/dev/ruby/decoder$ ./hacks2.rb
Args: []
Magic: true (TrueClass)
jdibling@hurricane:~/dev/ruby/decoder$ ./hacks2.rb --magic
Args: []
Magic: true (TrueClass)
jdibling@hurricane:~/dev/ruby/decoder$ ./hacks2.rb --no-magic
Args: []
Magic:  (NilClass)
jdibling@hurricane:~/dev/ruby/decoder$
```

Using `--no-magic` didn't result in `:magic => false`.  I could do something like:

```
options.magic = false if options.magic.nil?
```

But I don't want to.  That would defeat one of the purposes of using trollop in the first place.

Am I doing something wrong, or is it a bug in trollop?

Comment: Does it make a difference if you do `options[:magic]` like it shows in the Trollop docs instead of `options.magic`?

Comment: @Chuck:  Yes, I was doing it wrong, which I just figured out independantly.  Answering...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that Trollop returns options as a hash. This seems to work:

```
require 'trollop'

options = Trollop::options do
  banner "tester for trollop"
  opt :magic, "Use magic", :default => true
end

puts "Args: #{ARGV}\nMagic: #{options.magic} (#{options.magic.class})"
puts "Inspecting options: #{options.inspect}"
puts "#{options[:magic]}"
```

Returns:

```
Args: 
Magic:  (NilClass)
Inspecting options: {:help=>false, :magic=>false, :magic_given=>true}
false
```

Answer (score 1):

I was Doing It Wrong.

`options` here is a `Hash`.  I was accessing it as if `magic` were a member of `options`.

What I should have done was `options[:magic]`, rather than `options.magic`.

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'trollop'

options = Trollop::options do
    banner "tester for trollop"
    opt :magic, "Use magic", :default => true
end

# options.magic = false if options.magic.nil?

puts "Args: #{ARGV}\nMagic: #{options[:magic]} (#{options[:magic].class}) nil? #{options[:magic].class.nil?}"
```

Now it works (or rather, I'm using it) correctly:

```
jdibling@hurricane:~/dev/ruby/decoder$ ./hacks2.rb --no-magic
Args: []
Magic: false (FalseClass) nil? false
jdibling@hurricane:~/dev/ruby/decoder$
```

Comment: Downriver care to elaborate?